# Making drupal_goto Ignore ?destination=foo

Tags: 6, redirection

I frequently come across cases in my Drupal 6 sites where a user might encounter my module's pages with the ?destination=foo querystring appended to the URL, from previous interactions on the site. Results of this vary from "inconvenient" to "very aggravating."

The default behavior of `drupal_goto()` checks for the destination parameter first, and disregards the arguments to `drupal_goto()` if it is present.

Is there a Drupal-native way to use drupal_goto() in a way that ignores `destination`?

(Yes, I know I can recreate a version of `drupal_goto()` in a utility function, but I would prefer a Drupal-native solution if one exists)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's actually quite simple, just unset `$_REQUEST['destination']` before you invoke `drupal_goto()`.

Comment: That's so blindingly obvious, no wonder I missed it :)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, `unset($_REQUEST['destination'])` doesn't work for me, but I was able to get it work with this instead: `unset($_GET['destination'])`.

Comment: Odd, as `$_REQUEST` includes both `$_GET` and `$_POST` http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: You must be trying this in Drupal 7 then as its implementation of `drupal_goto` only checks for `$_GET['destination']`.