# 7 - drupal_goto() ignores $path if $_GET["destination"] is set?

Tags: 7, redirection

I have a Drupal 7 site that implements an OAuth Consumer using the [OAuth module](http://drupal.org/project/oauth). I have a page callback defined for `/oauth/login` that performs the first step of the dance, then redirects the user-agent to the authorization endpoint on the Provider via `drupal_goto()`. The site is configured to restrict access to all pages for "Anonymous User", and the "Access Denied" page is set to my custom callback.

When visiting a page as an unauthenticated user, however, Drupal goes into an infinite redirect loop. I traced the problem down to the logic in `drupal_goto()` itself, which inspects the value of `$_GET['destination']` and overwrites the `$path` argument before ever inspecting the value provided, thereby redirecting to the *original* path. This seems like a bug to me, but I recognize that I might just be "Doin It Rong", too.

Looks like there are a couple of other questions out here that are similar:

- [Drupal login not redirecting to SSO (external) server login page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40072/drupal-login-not-redirecting-to-sso-external-server-login-page) (Drupal 7)
- [drupal_goto ignored in custom form submit handler](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33277/drupal-goto-ignored-in-custom-form-submit-handler) (Drupal 7)
- [Making drupal_goto Ignore ?destination=foo](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/370/making-drupal-goto-ignore-destination-foo) (Drupal 6)

Does anyone have any insight as to why this behavior exists? I understand why the "destination" path exists and what it's used for, but it seems to me that `drupal_goto()` should only ignore the value of the `$path` argument if no value has been passed or the value passed matches the currently executed path. If it's a real bug, I'll submit a patch and some tests to cover the use cases.

Comment: You'd have to ask on Drupal.org really, I'd be surprised if anyone here knew the motivations behind the workflow of an arbitrary core function that was created that many years ago. It's almost certainly not a bug, it's been that way since [Drupal 4.6](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7). I'd like to think someone would have caught that by now if it's unintentional :) Either way, if you feel this is a bug I'm afraid you're in the wrong place - it'll need to be reported to the core issue queue

Comment: @Clive: Understood. Really just soliciting attention to the problem. Totally open to another way to do it, and I understand that `drupal_goto()` expires in D8, as well.

Comment: It is (thankfully). For the record I've always puzzled over the same thing - I just accept it these days and work around with unsetting GET vars or resetting static caches. I'd love to know they why as well, just not sure this is the best place to get the answer