# How to properly redirect users to their own pages from 404 or 404 error pages

Tags: redirection

Instead of using one of multiple contributed modules, which deal with redirections from error pages, I'd like to simply redirect users from the pages with other users uids in the path they tried to access to exactly the same pages, but with their own uids.

For example, if a user with uid '3' tried to access a page with the path `ssh-keys/user/4/add` then she should be redirected to `ssh-keys/user/3/add`. To achieve the goal I composed the following simple function:

```
function return_users_page_alter(&$page) {
  $current_path=(current_path());
  // make sure we have 'user' in path.
  if (strpos($current_path, 'user') !== false) { 
    global $user;
    // exclude site team members.
    if (!in_array('administrator', $user->roles) && !in_array('support', $user->roles) && !in_array('billing', $user->roles)) {
        $path_items=explode('/',$current_path);
        foreach ($path_items as $key => $value) {
          if ($value == 'user') {
            $found_uid = $path_items[$key+1];
            break;
          }
        }
        // If user is really different one.
        if ($user->uid != $path_items[$key+1]) {
          $redirect = str_replace($path_items[$key+1], $user->uid, $current_path);
          drupal_goto($redirect);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

but, unfortunately, it doesn't work. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading Clive's comments on [7 - drupal_goto() ignores $path if $_GET["destination"] is set?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85948/7-drupal-goto-ignores-path-if-getdestination-is-set), I've added added `unset($_GET['destination']);` just before `drupal_goto` command and it works now fine:

```
      unset($_GET['destination']);
      drupal_goto($external, array('external' => TRUE));
```